# Wireless LAN hard blocked on HP 15 r014-tx notebook

Tags: 16.04, networking, dual-boot, wireless

My wifi was working fine till yesterday. But now my wi-fi is disabled. It say
Hard blocked: yes.
I have tried rfkill and other stuff to no good.
I also tried pressing fn+f12 but nothing happened.
I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on dual boot with Windows 10.
Please help as I am in a middle of an important project.
Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Please run: `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod` As the result may be lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com We need to see the exact result; not just hard blocked: yes. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25025715/

Comment: Please see page 13 here: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04400096 It appears that wireless is an Action Key; not Fn+F12. Yes?

Comment: Yes, this wireless action key works well in windows. It turns white when my wifi is enabled in windows and red when I switch it off. But in ubuntu, this key is red the whole time. I've tried pressing it and also tried the the Fn+F12 combo.

Comment: I might have to uninstall this version and then install another version as my last option.

Comment: Does the action key work if you do: `sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi` ? If so, we can blacklist the module.

Comment: I again installed Ubuntu but the same issue still exists. I've  tried `sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi` but nothing happened.

Comment: Did it change the result of: `rfkill list all` after you pressed the action key or Fn+F12?

Comment: After I press the action key, Soft blocked turns to yes but hard blocked continues to be yes. The action key only changes the result of Soft blocked.